# Como puedo cambiar valores de un select usando JQuery?

Tags: jquery, dataset

Lo que quiero es que cuando yo presione los botones que están de color amarillo, el select se cambie dependiendo el botón que presione,por ejemplo si yo le doy click al botón antiparasitarios, el select debe cambiar a antiparasitarios y así sucesivamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado mi codigo jquery(que ahorita solo lo muestro en un alert)

```js
function showType(producto) {
    var productType = producto.getAttribute("data-product-type");
    alert(productType + ".");
  }
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" name="search_form" id="search_form" class="form-group form-horizontal">
<select name="users" onchange="" class="select-form center">
<option value="">Todos los Producto:</option>
<option value="antiparasitarios">Antiparasitarios</option>
<option value="antiparasitarios">Antibacterianos</option>
</select></form>
<div class="flex-item">
<button class="btn btn-product" type="button" name="button" onclick="showType(this)" data-product-type="antiparasitarios">Antiparasitarios</button>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-product" type="button" name="button" onclick="showType(this)" data-product-type="antiparasitarios">Antibacterianos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Francisco bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tendrías que explicar donde tendrían que buscarse los datos (según el tipo de producto) para llenar el `select`, si en una base de datos, si en un archivo, si en un array pre-existente, etc. Ese tipo de acciones suelen hacerse enviando una petición Ajax que busque los datos en el servidor y te los devuelva.

Comment: sería en una base de datos

Comment: Hace un par de días respondí a un requerimiento parecido al tuyo, explicando con detalle la forma de hacerlo. [Lo puedes revisar aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967), para que tengas un punto de partida, ya que son dos cosas diferentes las que tienes que preparar: por un lado el código de la página donde están los botones y por otra parte el código que se ejecuta en el servidor, que se conecta a la base de datos y te trae los datos según el criterio que le pases a la petición Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Sería de la siguiente manera utilizando JQuery:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        /*Delegamos un evento sobre los botones que tenga la clase btn-produc*/
                        $('.btn-product').on('click',function(){
                            /*Obtine el valor del atributo de este botón*/
                            var valor=$(this).attr("data-product-type");
                            /*Se le pasa el valor al select con el id select-formulario*/
                            $('#select-formulario').val(valor);
                        });
                    });

                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <form action="" method="POST" name="search_form" id="search_form" class="form-group form-horizontal">
                    <select name="users"  id="select-formulario" class="select-form center">
                        <option value="">Todos los Producto:</option>
                        <option value="antiparasitarios">Antiparasitarios</option>
                        <option value="antiparasitarios">Antibacterianos</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
                <div class="flex-item">
                    <button class="btn btn-product" type="button" name="button" data-product-type="antiparasitarios">Antiparasitarios</button>
                </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-product" type="button" name="button" data-product-type="antiparasitarios">Antibacterianos</button>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```