# enviar la variable seleccionada de un select por get

Tags: php, html

Tengo este archivo de php donde se elije el eje carga los Id de los indicadores que se le relacionan pero cuando intento mandarlos por Get a mi otro archivo de php me marca error de

> Notice: Undefined index: IndicadorEje in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SIEPRUEBAS\indicadores\VistaIndicador.php on line 11

Este es mi primer archivo de php

```
<?php

if ((!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || $_COOKIE['user'] == "") || (!isset($_COOKIE['IdSession']) || strlen($_COOKIE['IdSession']) != 15)) {
    header("Location: ../../../index.php");
}

include_once("../WEB-INF/Classes/Catalogo.class.php");
include_once("../WEB-INF/Classes/Indicadores.2.class.php");
$catalogo = new Catalogo();
$Eje="";
$indicadorEje="";
?>       
        <fieldset> 
            <legend>Indicadores por Eje</legend>
            <form action="indicadores/VistaIndicador.php" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputState">Eje</label>
                    <select id="Eje" class="form-control" name="Eje" onchange="cargarIndicadorPorEje();" >
                        <?php
                        $consulta = "SELECT
                             c_proyecto.IdProyecto,
                           c_proyecto.Nombre
                                  FROM
                             c_proyecto
                               ORDER BY
                         c_proyecto.Nombre ASC
                                                   ";
                        $resultado = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
                   echo '<option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>';
                   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                            $s = '';
                            if ($row['IdProyecto'] == $Eje) {
                                $s = 'selected="selected"';
                            }
                            echo '<option value="' . $row['IdProyecto'] . '" ' . $s . '>' . $row['Nombre'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>   

                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputState">Indicador</label>
                    <select id="IndicadorEje" class="form-control" name="IndicadorEje" onchange=""  >
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="row" id="recargar" >                    
                </div>
         </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Este es el segundo php

```
<?php
include_once("../WEB-INF/Classes/Catalogo.class.php");
include_once("../WEB-INF/Classes/Indicadores.2.class.php");
 $obj = new Indicadores2();
$catalogo = new Catalogo();
$IndicadorEje = $_GET['IndicadorEje'];
echo $altura;
```

Comment: Carlos bienvenido. Para próximas preguntas tómate el tiempo de identar mejor el código. Estaba ilegible, con un montón de líneas en blanco. Cuando copias/pegas código aquí asegúrate de quitarle las líneas en blanco, pegas todo, luego seleccionas todo el código y lo identas pulsando sobre los símbolos **`{ }`** que aparecen en el panel superior.

Comment: Si lo que quieres en llenar el `select` llamado `IndicadorEje` con el resultado de la consulta basada en el otro  `select` lo mejor sería hacer una petición Ajax al servidor, recoger los datos y luego llenar ese `select` con los datos traídos de la base de datos. Interpreto que es eso lo que quieres, un `select` dependiente. ¿Es eso lo que quieres o no?

Comment: si esa es la idea que dependiendo de la opcion del primer select salga las opciones que le corresponden en el segundo select para asi mandarlo al otro php

Comment: Carlos [aquí hay una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967) donde se explica con detalle cómo creer `select` dependientes. Sólo tendrías que adaptarla. Ese código usa Ajax, que sería lo más adecuado para este tipo de casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu select IndicadorEje no tiene options, por eso no está disponible en la variable GET tan solo tendrías disponible la variable Eje del select superior q si tiene options

Comment: ese select se carga mediante un js y un controlador como podría mandar el id que selecciona a ese segundo php

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ante mano Gracias me podrían ayudar a saber como mandar el id por medio de GET otra pagina  Y Asi poder procesar el registro

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, además de [ask] y [mcve] para saber cómo realizar una buena prgeunta. Siendo esta la sección de respuestas, no deberías publicar en ella una pregunta, tampoco es conveniente dejar el código en formato imagen, es mejor copiarlo. Saludos :)