# Realizar consulta SQL cada vez que cambia un select, HTML PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, html5

Tengo este código en un documento php

```
<div class="gaps">
    <p>Fecha primer asesoría</p>
        <select id="fecha1" class="form-control" name="primer-fecha">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php
                include 'conexion.php';
                $consulta1="SELECT * FROM fechas_asesorias WHERE status='AC'";
                $ejecutar1=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta1) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($ejecutar1 as $opciones1): ?>                                    
                <option value="<?php echo $opciones1['fecha'] ?>"><?php echo $opciones1['fecha'] ?></option>                                
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="gaps">
    <p>Hora primer asesoría</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="primer_hora">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php foreach ($ejecutar2 as $opciones2): ?>                                    
                <option value="<?php echo $opciones2['hora'] ?>"><?php echo $opciones2['hora'] ?></option>                              
            <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

En el primer select se llena con los datos que obtiene de la consulta SQL que realizo mediante código php y lo que quiero lograr en el segundo select es que me aparezcan las horas disponibles que le corresponden a la fecha que seleccionen en el primer select, según yo coloque esta función, la cual no se si está bien

```
<script>
    $("#fecha1").change(function (event) {
        <?php
            include 'conexion.php';
            $Valor1=document.getElementById(fecha1).value;
            $obtenerID1="SELECT id FROM fechas_asesorias WHERE fecha=$Valor1";
            $IDFecha1=mysqli_query($conexion,$obtenerID1) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

            $consulta2="SELECT * FROM horas_asesorias WHERE status='AC' AND id_fecha=$IDFecha1";
            $ejecutar2=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
        ?>
    });
</script>
```

¿Alguien que me pueda echar una mano?

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo detalladado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967) para montar un `select` dependiente de otro usando Ajax, que sería lo más idóneo en este caso. El segundo `select` se llenaría con los datos adecuados cada vez que el primer `select` cambie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza ajax para obtener la información de tu consulta

ejemplo:

```
$("#fecha1").change(function (event) {
    var fecha1=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        // aqui pasarias el valor de fecha1
        data: {"fecha1" : fecha1},
        //
        type: "GET",
        // 
        dataType: "json",
        // URL 
        url: "consulta.php",
    })
     .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
         //aqui recorrerias data para rellenar tu segundo select
         console.log( "ok" );

     })
     .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

             console.log( "error: " +  textStatus);

    });
});
```

en consulta.php

```
<?php
$Valor1=$_POST["fecha1"];
            include 'conexion.php';

            $obtenerID1="SELECT id FROM fechas_asesorias WHERE fecha=$Valor1";
            $IDFecha1=mysqli_query($conexion,$obtenerID1) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

            $consulta2="SELECT * FROM horas_asesorias WHERE status='AC' AND id_fecha=$IDFecha1";
$myArray = array();
            $ejecutar2=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
while ($row = $ejecutar2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
        ?>
```

Comment: O sea, en el `onchange` del primer select habría que lanzar la petición Ajax, mandando a buscar al servidor los elementos dependientes de ese elemento que se seleccionó. Luego en el `done` habría que cargar el segundo select con los datos traídos de Ajax. Eso es lo que se llama selects dependientes. Aquí mismo creo que hay algunos ejemplos.

Comment: Me sirvió lo de ajax, te lo agradezco mucho