# Recargar pagina php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estoy creando un combo con 2 elementos `select`, el segundo elemento `select` requiere de la selección del primer `select` para poner valores por medio de una consulta a base de datos. Para ello necesito recargar la pagina, lo cual no he logrado hacer al momento, el código que tengo es:

`Javascript`

```
function seleccionados() {
       var gerencia = document.getElementById("gerencia").value;
       console.log(gerencia);
       $.post("box_administrador.php",{$datosN},function(mensaje){
           $("nombre_colaborador").html(mensaje);
       })
    }
```

`HTML` y `PHP`

```
<tr>
    <th>Gerencia</th>
    <td>
        <select id="gerencia" name="gerencia" >
            <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
            <?php
                foreach ($datosG as $dat) {
                $gerencia = $dat->gerencia;
            ?>
                <option  value="<?php echo $dat->gerencia; ?>" onchange="javascript:seleccionados();"><?php echo utf8_encode($gerencia); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <th>Colaborador</th>
    <td>
    <select id="nombre_colaborador" name="nombre_colaborador">
        <option value="0">-- Seleccione --</option>
        <?php
            foreach($datosN as $dn){
            $nombre = $dn->nombre;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $dn->nombre; ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($nombre); ?></option>
```

Las variables **$datosN** y **$datosG** son objetos que traen `array` de base de datos.

Comment: Mejor hazlo con Ajax, así puedes actualizar los datos del `select` dependiente sin necesidad de recargar la página. Aquí mismo hay varias/preguntas respuestas que tratan sobre el tema de los select dependientes. Con Ajax es mucho mejor y más elegante. Recargar la página es siempre molesto y más costoso.

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo intentare, la cuestión es que la función es solo de consulta. solo para mostrar datos.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967) que explica los conceptos fundamentales para un caso igual al tuyo, sólo que allí era un contexto un poco más complejo porque los datos eran pedidos usando un modelo. No obstante si aplicas esos mismos principios podrás hacerlo. Lo importante es que entiendas cómo funciona, entendiendo eso, sea cual sea la forma de obtener/consultar los datos es lo de menos. Si te decides por Ajax (te lo recomiendo) estaremos aquí para ayudarte con cualquier duda y cuando aprendas a usarlo no te vas a arrepentir.