# Javascript y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, select, combobox

de nuevo preguntando..

Intento llenar un SELECT dependiendo del valor elegido en otro SELECT

```
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="Combobox1" onchange="rellena()"......>
```

El segundo SELECT y la funcion rellena()..y como puedo sustituir en el `"Where Delegacion=1"` por "`Where Delegacion=(valor del primer select.)`", por que me estoy liando y encabezonando en algo que no está bien....

```
        <select name="Comboboxx" size="1" id="Comboboxx"  style="position:absolute;left:680px;top:100px;width:150px;height:28px;z-index:3;">
        <option value="0">Seleccione Obra</option>
        
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    
          
        function rellena(){
          
        <?php 
        
        $conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or
        die("Imposible concectar con Mysql");
        mysql_select_db("ad6138",$conexion) or
        die("No se encuentra la base de datos");  
        
        $buscaObra=mysql_query("SELECT  `obra`.`NObra`,`obra`.`Codigo`
         FROM `obra`
        WHERE Delegacion=1",$conexion) or
        die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
        
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($buscaObra))
        {
        
        echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row['Codigo'].'">'.$row['NObra'].'</OPTION>';
        
        }
        
        
        ?>
        
        }
        </SCRIPT>
</select>
```

GRacias a Todos...

Comment: No puedes ejecutar código PHP (servidor) directamente en una función Javascript (cliente), porque se manejan en contextos diferentes y solo pueden comunicarse mediante AJAX. Tal vez esto te sirva de guía: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129955/select-dependientes-php-ajax-mysql

Comment: Hola Aldeano, por favor lee sobre [ask]. Esta pregunta tiene problemas graves de formato (el título no es descriptivo, debes indicar si recibes algún error, qué resultado esperas y cuál obtienes, etc.) Además, si [buscas e investigas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search), encontrarás que esta pregunta se ha realizado ya en el sitio (no exactamente igual, pero parecida).

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama *select dependientes*, es decir, dependiendo de un `select` se llena otro `select` con las opciones dependientes (lo que ocurre por ejemplo cuando seleccionar una provincia y en otro select se cargan todas las ciudades de esa provincia). Esto se suele hacer con Ajax, de hecho si mal no recuerdo hay aquí varias preguntas/respuestas que tratan ese tema y explican cómo hacerlo.

Comment: [Aquí tienes una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129995/29967) del tipo *step by step*, pensada para programadores que no conocen Ajax o empiezan con él. En ella se explica precisamente cómo hacer un `select` dependiente usando MySQL.